# java Returning a string in a method inside else statement

Tags: java

I need to return `toscanText` String from `scanText()` to main method but i could not figure out a way to return that string inside from the else statement .

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

public class ReverseString {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Debug check");
        String scannedString = scanText();

    }

    public static String scanText() {
        System.out.println("Enter the string");
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        String toScanText = scanner.next();
        int stringLength = toScanText.length();

        if (stringLength == 0) {
            System.out.println("Enter the string again");
            scanText();
        }else if(stringLength>0){
            return toScanText;
        }


    }

    public static String reverseMethod(String toReverseString){


        System.out.println("debug check");
        toReverseString="this string";
        return toReverseString;
    }
}
```

Comment: What should be returned if the method does not go into the `else` block?

Comment: You have to use a return statement in your if bloc. Here I think you can type `return scanText();` and use else instead of else if as your textLength should never be less than 0

Comment: @Imaguest that would work if `scanText()` would not create a `new Scanner` everytime.

Comment: @f1sh I didn't test it but it works no? As the scanners are not closed. It's not clean at all, I would prefer a while loop approach 100% of time

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String scanText() {
    boolean noValidString = true;
    System.out.println("Enter the string");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    while(noValidString) {
        String toScanText = scanner.next();

        if (toScanText.length(); == 0) {
            System.out.println("Enter the string again");
        } else {
            noValidString = false;
    }
    return toScanText;
}
```

My primitive approach without introducing new concepts. There is no need going for a recursive method call here. Also the scanner should be closed at some point before the `return` using `scanner.close()`

Comment: System.in object is opened by the JVM, you should leave it to the JVM to close it, especially if you want for some reason to read an user input later in your app.